# When configuring dnsmasq for PXE booting, why do I need to change undionly.kpxe to undionly.0?

Tags: dhcp, pxe-boot, dnsmasq, coreos

I have configured dnsmasq to PXE boot iPXE clients by referring them to a HTTP server ([matchbox](https://coreos.com/matchbox/docs/latest/) in this case). I have also configured it to deal with older PXE clients by placing a copy of iPXE in the root of my TFTP server to allow these older clients to chainload to iPXE. To do this, I have used the following line in my dnsmasq.conf:

```
dhcp-boot=tag:!ipxe,undionly.kpxe
```

I have placed the `undionly.kpxe` file at the root of my TFTP server, however a few places say that you need to symlink or copy `undionly.kpxe` to `undionly.kpxe.0` or `undionly.0` ([CoreOS](https://coreos.com/matchbox/docs/latest/network-setup.html#pxe-enabled-dhcp), [FOG Wiki](https://wiki.fogproject.org/wiki/index.php/Using_FOG_with_an_unmodifiable_DHCP_server/_Using_FOG_with_no_DHCP_server#DNSMASQ_settings_for_iPXE#DNSMASQ_settings_for_iPXE)).

Firstly, why does dnsmasq not look for the exact filename you specify in the config and secondly which one is the correct one, undionly.0 or undionly.kpxe.0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the filename ending in .0 is only relevant for versions of dnsmasq prior to 2.76. from the changelog of 2.76:

> Subtle change in the semantics of "basename" in
>       --pxe-service. The historical behaviour has always been
>       that the actual filename downloaded from the TFTP server
>       is . where  is an integer which
>       corresponds to the layer parameter supplied by the client.
>       It's not clear what the function of the "layer" 
>       actually is in the PXE protocol, and in practise layer 
>       is always zero, so the filename is .0
>       The new behaviour is the same as the old, except when
>        includes a file suffix, in which case
>       the layer suffix is no longer added. This allows
>       sensible suffices to be used, rather then the
>       meaningless ".0". Only in the unlikely event that you
>       have a config with a basename which already has a
>       suffix, is this an incompatible change, since the file
>       downloaded will change from name.suffix.0 to just 
>       name.suffix

if you are using a version of dnsmasq after 2.76 just use the actual filename. if using a version from prior, use "filename".0